# Measuring accuracy with Forecast package in R

Tags: r, forecast

I created data set with artificial data. Below you can see the code and data.

```
library(dplyr)
library(ggplot2)
library(forecast)

    MY_DATA_input<-data.frame( 
        Sales1=rnorm(72, mean=1000, sd=500),
        Sales2=rnorm(72, mean=800, sd=400))
    
    
    MY_DATA<-ts(MY_DATA_input,start=c(2014,1),end=c(2019,11),frequency = 12)
```

This dataset contains data about Sales 1 and Sales 2 from 2014 until 2019. So my intention is to make projections with the forecast package and Snaive function simultaneously for both sales.So below you can see function for that forcast

```
    hrz<-13 # Forecast horizont
    
    
    train<-window(MY_DATA, start = 2014, end = 2017)
    test<-window(MY_DATA, start = 2017, end = 2019)
    
seasons<-as.numeric(12)
    
    FORECASTING_FUNCTION_SNAIVE <- function(Z, hrz = forecast_horizon) {
      timeseries <- msts(Z, start = year_start, seasonal.periods = seasons)
        forecast <- snaive(timeseries, h =  hrz)
    }
    
    FORECASTING_LIST_SNAIVE <- lapply(X = train, FORECASTING_FUNCTION_SNAIVE)
```

This function works well and now I want to see the model's accuracy separate for the train and separate for the test set.

I tried with the function from the Forecast package and also I add my previous function but is not work.

```
accuracy(forecast(FORECASTING_LIST_SNAIVE,h=13),x=test)
```

So can anybody help me how to solve this problem? In the end, I need to receive output in format describe below (not figures,only format)

```
Sales 1
                           ME      RMSE       MAE          MPE       MAPE      MASE      ACF1 Theil's U
    Training set -0.008482101 0.4669167 0.2819318 -0.002732195 0.08538727 0.2279921 0.1088535        NA
    Test set     -0.609225233 0.8249255 0.6805894 -0.170113066 0.18997189 0.5503777 0.8193659 0.6217957

Sales 2
                           ME      RMSE       MAE          MPE       MAPE      MASE      ACF1 Theil's U
    Training set  0.009771848 0.2770957 0.2220807  0.002654923 0.06701084 0.1795918 0.1124374        NA
    Test set     -0.980333471 1.1563839 1.0294249 -0.273341488 0.28703793 0.8324733 0.8381198 0.8725192
```

Comment: Can you dput `seasons` df??

Comment: For seasons I used this line seasons<-as.numeric(12)